# Google Scripts - Custom Menu to open fillable HTML Form and append response values to the Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a fillable HTML form that can be opened from a custom menu within a Google Spreadsheet. The form is opening as expected, and the onSuccess() script is executing. The issue I am having is that the values are not being added to the spreadsheet.

Here is the .gs file:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom')
    .addItem('New Entry', 'openForm')
    .addToUi();
}


function openForm() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'New Entry');
}


function AddToSheet(InputOne, InputTwo, InputThree) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet_Name');
  sheet.appendRow([InputOne, InputTwo, InputThree]);
}
```

And here is the HTML file (index.html)

```
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <fieldset>

        <input type="text" id="fieldA" name="Field 1">

        <input type="number" id="fieldB" name="Field 2">

        <input type="text" id="fieldC" name="Field 3">

        <input type="button" value="Save Input" onclick="WriteInput()">

        <input type="reset" value="Reset">

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    function onFailure(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function onSuccess() {
      alert("Your INPUT was SAVED!");
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function WriteInput() {
      var strngOne = document.getElementById("fieldA").value;
      var strngTwo = document.getElementById("fieldB").value;
      var strngThree = document.getElementById("fieldC").value;


      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .AddToSheet(strngOne, strngTwo, strngThree);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is. Everything is working as expect for the values appending to the Spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I just pasted your code as is into a script, renamed the default sheet to "Sheet_Name" and it worked as is. Have you tried adding logging calls to debug what's going on? Particularly in `AddToSheet()`. In addition, it would also be useful to include the execution transcript.

Comment: Hmm thanks chuckx! you are right it is working. It seems that when I cleaned up the script for this post I inadvertently fixed the problem.